# On Mac OS X in C++ on a 64-bit CPU, is there a type that is 64 bits?

Tags: c++, macos, 64-bit

I can't use "long long"; what should I be using?

Comment: Why can't you use `long long`?  Does your compiler not support it?

Comment: Does Darwin/MacOSX support the fixed size integer typedefs, like int64_t?  If so, I'd use those.  See http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6.2 - Intel), then 'long' is 64-bits with the default compiler.

Specify 'g++ -m64' and it will likely be 64-bits on earlier versions too.

```
 1 = sizeof(char)
 1 = sizeof(unsigned char)
 2 = sizeof(short)
 2 = sizeof(unsigned short)
 4 = sizeof(int)
 4 = sizeof(unsigned int)
 8 = sizeof(long)
 8 = sizeof(unsigned long)
 4 = sizeof(float)
 8 = sizeof(double)
16 = sizeof(long double)
 8 = sizeof(size_t)
 8 = sizeof(ptrdiff_t)
 8 = sizeof(time_t)
 8 = sizeof(void *)
 8 = sizeof(char *)
 8 = sizeof(short *)
 8 = sizeof(int *)
 8 = sizeof(long *)
 8 = sizeof(float *)
 8 = sizeof(double *)
 8 = sizeof(int (*)(void))
 8 = sizeof(double (*)(void))
 8 = sizeof(char *(*)(void))
```

Tested with:

```
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

Compiling with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with option `-std=c99`, the output from the program is more extensive.  Thanks to [apalopohapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615430/apalopohapa) for pointing out the oversight that `long long` etc were missing from the original.

```
 1 = sizeof(char)
 1 = sizeof(unsigned char)
 2 = sizeof(short)
 2 = sizeof(unsigned short)
 4 = sizeof(int)
 4 = sizeof(unsigned int)
 8 = sizeof(long)
 8 = sizeof(unsigned long)
 4 = sizeof(float)
 8 = sizeof(double)
16 = sizeof(long double)
 8 = sizeof(size_t)
 8 = sizeof(ptrdiff_t)
 8 = sizeof(time_t)
 8 = sizeof(long long)
 8 = sizeof(unsigned long long)
 8 = sizeof(uintmax_t)
 1 = sizeof(int8_t)
 2 = sizeof(int16_t)
 4 = sizeof(int32_t)
 8 = sizeof(int64_t)
 1 = sizeof(int_least8_t)
 2 = sizeof(int_least16_t)
 4 = sizeof(int_least32_t)
 8 = sizeof(int_least64_t)
 1 = sizeof(int_fast8_t)
 2 = sizeof(int_fast16_t)
 4 = sizeof(int_fast32_t)
 8 = sizeof(int_fast64_t)
 8 = sizeof(uintptr_t)
 8 = sizeof(void *)
 8 = sizeof(char *)
 8 = sizeof(short *)
 8 = sizeof(int *)
 8 = sizeof(long *)
 8 = sizeof(float *)
 8 = sizeof(double *)
 8 = sizeof(int (*)(void))
 8 = sizeof(double (*)(void))
 8 = sizeof(char *(*)(void))
 1 = sizeof(struct { char a; })
 2 = sizeof(struct { short a; })
 4 = sizeof(struct { int a; })
 8 = sizeof(struct { long a; })
 4 = sizeof(struct { float a; })
 8 = sizeof(struct { double a; })
16 = sizeof(struct { char a; double b; })
16 = sizeof(struct { short a; double b; })
16 = sizeof(struct { long a; double b; })
 4 = sizeof(struct { char a; char b; short c; })
16 = sizeof(struct { char a; char b; long c; })
 4 = sizeof(struct { short a; short b; })
 6 = sizeof(struct { char a[3]; char b[3]; })
 8 = sizeof(struct { char a[3]; char b[3]; short c; })
16 = sizeof(struct { long double a; })
32 = sizeof(struct { char a; long double b; })
16 = sizeof(struct { char a; long long b; })
16 = sizeof(struct { char a; uintmax_t b; })
```

Comment: Additionally, if you include <types.h>, you can use int64_t, and uint64_t, which are typedef'd to the appropriate type type, and makes it explicit what you are using.

Comment: int64_t *at al* are actually in <stdint.h>

Comment: Relying on the table you just posted is bad advice.  If you want 64 bits, use `int64_t`.  It's standard for a reason.

Comment: @apalopohapa: MIA — pure oversight.  I must either have compiled an old version or have compiled without `-std=c99`.  The code dated 2010-03-05 produces many extra values when compiled with `-std=c99`.  See update — and thanks for the question.

Answer (score 6):

Include `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` (the later is found on some more compilers, but both are provided by the Apple compiler), and use `uint64_t` and `int64_t`. They are 64-bit on both 32-bit and 64-bit targets.